# tsconfig baseURL and paths made build import point to source folder

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs, tsc, tsconfig

I am compiling my module into a ES5 dependency without JSX code. But when I am using baseUrl and paths to have root import supported, my build folder have some code that point directly to the source (which have JSX) unexpectedly. Once I remove the baseUrl and paths options, it returns back to enclosed build.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "*",
        "src/*"
      ]}}
}
```

Is there any way to fix it while still using 'tsc' or do I have to use a babel transpiler for this case.

```
// in the source file
import _var from 'styles/variableStyles';
```

```
// in the build file
var variableStyles_1 = __importDefault(require("styles/variableStyles"));
```

```
// the error
 Unexpected token (15:9)

  13 |   const Component = component;
  14 |   const attachClassname = props.className || '';
> 15 |   return <Component {...props} className={`${globalClassNames.join(' ')} ${attachClassname}`} />;
     |          ^
  16 | };
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling

Comment: The file you're compiling has a `.tsx` extension right? And you've enabled jsx in `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: yes, I did. But I mean the problem is that the build link some of the code's import to the source code's file. Which broke the encapsulation of my build.